# Error with calling graphQl mutation from react app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I try to call simple graphQl mutation from react app. It is mutation description:

```
createOrganization(
organization: OrganizationInput!
): Organization

type OrganizationInput {
name: String!
type: String
billingAddress: AddressInput
shippingAddress: AddressInput
}
```

My attempt to call it:

```
const CREATE_ORGANIZATION = gql`
  mutation createOrganization($organization: OrganizationInput!) {
    _id
  }
`;
const [mutation] = useMutation(CREATE_ORGANIZATION);
...
mutation({
          variables: { name: '' },
        });
```

Unfortunately graphQl doesn't provide any readable logs, and I have:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400
new ApolloError
src/errors/ApolloError.ts:46
  43 | // Constructs an instance of ApolloError given a GraphQLError
  44 | // or a network error. Note that one of these has to be a valid
  45 | // value or the constructed error will be meaningless.
> 46 | constructor({
     | ^  47 |   graphQLErrors,
  48 |   networkError,
  49 |   errorMessage,
```

In network I see that mutation was called, but I have no idea what wrong and the most important how to handle issues when you work with graphQl.

p.s. It is working mutation - not problem to call it from playgraund.

Comment: make it working in playground **using 'query variables'** (only one 'organization' param) - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ... then recreate in code

Comment: changed to mutation({
          variables: { organization: { name: '' } },
        });      Still it does not work. Not any problem in playground

Comment: still bad syntax

Comment: I don't understand... I see many samples and everywhere the same simple approach.

Comment: simply missleading by hardcoding ... follow this docs and this way of passing vars

Comment: 'thanks' for next question about bad passing variables - use search

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. It was in gql. Correct version is:

```
const CREATE_ORGANIZATION = gql`
  mutation($organization: OrganizationInput!) {
    createOrganization(organization: $organization) {
      _id
    }
  }
`;
```